# hide a View from a single item in Row (collectionViewCell Item)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

sometimes my ColectionViewCell's progress bar is not visible ,
 i have some items at every row and below am trying to hide  ProgressBar of a single item but my progress bar got hidden from all of the items of a row

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",
                                                                         forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let url = NSURL(string: "\(attachedImgUrlDict[collectionView.tag]![indexPath.item])")// its a Url 
            cell.imgViewOfCell.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.CacheMemoryOnly, progress: {
                (receivedSize, expectedSize) -> Void in
                // Update progress here

                cell.loaderView.progress = CGFloat(receivedSize)/CGFloat(expectedSize)

            }) {
                (image, error, _, _) -> Void in
                // Reveal image here

                cell.imgViewOfCell.image = self.ResizeImage( image , targetSize: CGSizeMake( cell.imgViewOfCell.frame.width ,  cell.imgViewOfCell.frame.height))

                cell.loaderView.hidden =  true // am hiding the progress bar here when the loads complete (of a single item) but seems like its hiding the progressView of all items in the row  

            }
        return cell
    }
```

any idea how to fix this ???

Comment: when your progress bar hidden? which cell you hidden?

Comment: i dint get you man @IyyappanRavi what you asking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just a short overview, So you get your answer**

UICollectionView is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UICollectionView, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows.

**So, now, coming to your answer**

When you scroll your CollectionView, collectionView datasource method gets called again for every indexPath, and it reuses the hidden cells, Thus in other cell, where you hide your progress bar, gets reused and it still shows progress bar hidden

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

**SOLUTION**

RESET YOUR PROGRESS BAR VISIBILITY FOR EVERY CELL On call of cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",
                                                                         forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.loaderView.hidden =  false //RESET ITS VISIBILITY


        let url = NSURL(string: "\(attachedImgUrlDict[collectionView.tag]![indexPath.item])")// its a Url 
            cell.imgViewOfCell.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.CacheMemoryOnly, progress: {

                //SAME CODE

            }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming You have fixed number of cells in UICollectionView.

Tip for solving such problem, `when you have controls in UICollectionViewCell or UITableViewCell, give tag to your controls depending upon your indexPath`.

case 1 : If CollectionView is sectional, then your tags will be like [0][0], [1][0] ... In such case do something like this,

```
collectionViewCell.progressBar.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.item] intValue]; // If it is sectional collection view
```

case 2 : If Collection View is non-sectional,do something like this,

```
collectionViewCell.progressBar.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.item] intValue]; // If it is non-sectional collection view
```

Hope this will solve your problem or give you idea to manage accordingly.
If you have more than one control in your cell then just give tags like indexPath.item + 1 + 2 ...